# Angular Routing on App Start Up

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I have a web page, made with Angular, and i want to load the main content body of the page dynamically. so i made my body a seperate component and laid out the path so that i could route to it. i want my app to load it as soon as the app starts, but first it has too load at all ;).

```
<div *ngIf="this.inboundButton" id="maincontainer" class="ScMainContent sticky-ready">
  <div class="sf_cols">
    <div class="sf_colsOut sf_1col_1_100">
      <div id="mainContentPlaceHolder_T15DDBF9D005_COL00" class="sf_colsIn sf_1col-1in-100">

        <p>
          Hello Welcome to my Home Element!
          <br/>
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']" href="">
          it Doesnt Work at All.
          </a>
        </p>
        <router-outlet name="home"></router-outlet>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the button in my html was put in to check to ensure that it didnt need my interaction to load. it didnt.

my routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {InboundComponent} from './screens/inbound/inbound.component'
import {OutboundComponent} from './screens/outbound/outbound.component'
import {HomeComponent} from './screens/home/home.component'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import { HeaderComponent } from "app/screens/header/header.component";
import { FooterComponent } from "app/screens/footer/footer.component";

const routes: Routes = [
   {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'home',
     pathMatch: 'full'
   },
   {
     path: 'home',
     component: HomeComponent
   },
   {
     path: 'header',
     component: HeaderComponent
   },
   {
     path: 'footer',
     component: FooterComponent
   },
   {
     path: 'inbound',
     component: InboundComponent
   },
   {
     path: 'outbound',
     component: OutboundComponent
   }
 ];

 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the text displays properly so i know the html loads, but at the router-outlet it just does nothing.

i have read through almost all the documentation on routing and this seems to be right... but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You should change your redirectTo for '/home', then the app will load to with an initial url of '' and it will redirect you to '/home', loading the component you want.

Comment: @Supamiu still doesn't load :(

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: @RRForUI nope. all is good in console land.

Comment: I still don't understand why do you need to use router outlet since its going to load by default. Just throw in body component's html selector

Comment: @RRForUI because over time my page will just be a route to my header, a route to my body, and a route to my footer. making it easier for our end users to dynamically disable or enable any htm elements they don't wish to have simply by shutting down the route

Comment: Did you finally got it working?

Answer (score 0):

> just change the first route, set redirectTo: 'home'

```
   {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: '/home',
     pathMatch: 'full'
   },
```

Comment: unfortunatly, this doesn't fix it. i originally had home set as my default path but it doesn't load it either.

Comment: you cannot state with `/` when defining routes

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like below

```
{
     path: '',
    children:[
       path:'home',
       component:HomeComponent
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to activate the router in ngOnInit() of the AppComponent...

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
   }
```